# play-clj Android: Access accelerometer

Tags: android, clojure, accelerometer, gyroscope, play-clj

I want to try an acceleration-based application in play-clj, but I'm not quite sure how to access gyroscope and accelerometer from clojure.

In Java I'd access `Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX()`. play-clj does not offer matching events in its `defscreen` macro, and I can't figure out the syntax to call the `Gdx.input`-accelerometer directly.

```
(import 'com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx) ;; Gdx should be a singleton, right?
(.-input Gdx) ;; no such field
(.input Gdx)  ;; no such method
```

Now what should I do? Should I prefer to access the device's sensors directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Gdx, but the [Javadoc for com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Gdx.html) tells me that `Gdx.input` is a static field of the `Gdx` class, not the field of a singleton instance.

The correct Java interop should therefore be:

```
(import 'com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx)
(.getGyroscopeX Gdx/input)
```

Comment: You're right... the possibility of a static field didn't come to my mind, I always used it as if it were a singleton when I wrote Java apps with it. Your solution works like a charm.